# iOS skeleton loading animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer, caanimation, cagradientlayer

I am working on adding skeleton loading to an iOS app. I have a UICollectionView where each cell should display a "loading" state while data is being loaded. To handle this state, a skeleton loading technique is going to be used.

For this case, I am just taking the labels and images, and adding a sublayer to them that is a gray sublayer, masked by the bounds of each label or image. This is working fine.

The problem is that I also want a "sheen" or "shimmer" animation that goes across each view, from left to right and it repeats. But I cannot get the animation to work. It just looks like this, without any animation. The second item is lighter in color because it is disabled, otherwise they would all be the same color. But everything looks fine, it is just that there is supposed to be an animation.

[image]

## Code

Here is the code that I have. Again, the problem is that the animation is not happening. There is supposed to be a CAGradientLayer that starts to the left, out of view, and animates to the right, until it gets out of view. And then it all repeats.

```objectivec
@interface MyCollectionViewCell ()

/**
 * If this is YES, then the skeleton loading layers and animation need to be shown.
 * If this is NO, then the normal view should be shown. No skeleton loading layers should be shown.
 */
@property (assign, nonatomic, getter=isLoading) BOOL loading;

@end

@implementation MyCollectionViewCell

//... initialization and other logic

/**
 * This finds the direct subviews of the contentView that are either labels or images.
 */
- (NSArray<__kindof UIView *> *)loadableSubviews {
    NSMutableArray<UIView *> *views = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (UIView *view in self.contentView.subviews) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
            [views addObject:view];
        } else if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
            [views addObject:view];
        }
    }
    return views;
}

- (void)setLoading:(BOOL)loading {
    self->_loading = loading;
    
    NSArray<__kindof UIView *> *loadingViews = [self loadableSubviews];
    
    if (loading) {
        //display the skeleton loading layers

        UIColor *backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(210.0/255.0) green:(210.0/255.0) blue:(210.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];
        UIColor *highlightColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(235.0/255.0) green:(235.0/255.0) blue:(235.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];
        CALayer *skeletonLayer = [CALayer layer];
        skeletonLayer.backgroundColor = backgroundColor.CGColor;
        skeletonLayer.name = @"skeletonLayer";
        skeletonLayer.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
        skeletonLayer.frame = UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds;
        
        for (UIView *loadingView in loadingViews) {
            CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [[CAGradientLayer alloc] init];
            gradientLayer.colors = @[backgroundColor, highlightColor, backgroundColor];
            gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.5);
            gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5);
            gradientLayer.frame = UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds;
            gradientLayer.name = @"skeletonGradient";
            
            loadingView.layer.mask = skeletonLayer;
            [loadingView.layer addSublayer:skeletonLayer];
            [loadingView.layer addSublayer:gradientLayer];
            loadingView.clipsToBounds = YES;
            
            CGFloat width = UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.width;
            
            CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.x"];
            animation.duration = 3.0;

            //TODO: is there maybe something wrong with the y coordinate here?
            animation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(-width, gradientLayer.frame.origin.y)];
            animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(width, gradientLayer.frame.origin.y)];
            animation.repeatCount = CGFLOAT_MAX;
            animation.autoreverses = NO;
            animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
            
            [gradientLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"gradientShimmer"];
        }
    } else {
        //remove the skeleton loading layers

        for (UIView *loadingView in loadingViews) {
            for (NSInteger x = loadingView.layer.sublayers.count - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
                CALayer *sublayer = loadingView.layer.sublayers[x];
                if ([sublayer.name isEqualToString:@"skeletonLayer"] || [sublayer.name isEqualToString:@"skeletonGradient"]) {
                    [sublayer removeFromSuperlayer];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@end
```

## Debugging

I added a breakpoint after adding the animation to the layer and inspected the `gradientLayer` in LLDB and it shows the animation is attached to the layer:

```
(lldb) po gradientLayer
<CAGradientLayer:0x280964380; name = "skeletonGradient"; position = CGPoint (187.5 406); bounds = CGRect (0 0; 375 812); allowsGroupOpacity = YES; name = skeletonGradient; endPoint = CGPoint (1 0.5); startPoint = CGPoint (0 0.5); colors = (
    "UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0.823529 0.823529 0.823529 1",
    "UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0.921569 0.921569 0.921569 1",
    "UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0.823529 0.823529 0.823529 1"
); animations = [gradientShimmer=<CABasicAnimation: 0x2809645e0>]>
```

But for some reason it does not appear to be running.

## Questions

1. Does anyone know why the animation is not working?
2. Is there a better way to do any of this?
3. In particular, is there a better way to remove the loading state? Is there a better way to remove these layers?

Comment: You do know that you can't add something and animate it all in one go? To be animated, a thing needs to be part of the render tree already. Might not be relevant, but it might be.

Comment: Also note that you cannot make skeletonLayer both a mask and a sublayer.

Comment: @matt - thank you so much for your help. In order to make this part of the render tree first, should I add this layer in the init function or is there a different way to make it be part of the render tree? And for your second comment, do you know how I could do this? And are there any good ways of debugging Core Animation issues like this? I can use LLDB to find out the animation object is added to the layer, but I don’t know how to find out how to fix issues like this. Thank you so much for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set an array of UIColor objects to the `colors` property of gradientLayer. Instead you have to use CGColors, see Apple's documentation here:

> An array of CGColorRef objects defining the color of each gradient stop. Animatable.

see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cagradientlayer/1462403-colors?language=objc

So this means that you should change the assignment as follows:

```
gradientLayer.colors = @[(id)backgroundColor.CGColor, (id)highlightColor.CGColor, (id)backgroundColor.CGColor];
```

**Test**

In the small animated GIF the gray gradients are not as good as in reality, but you can see that it gives the expected result

[image: Test]

Comment: Yes, thank you so much. That worked. I just overlooked that detail, but it is looking great now. Thanks again. Do you happen to know any reason why the removing of the sublayers is not working? This is question three in the questions section. I can also open a new question. But when I try to do something like `cell.loading = NO`, it doesn't remove the loading effect. I ran LLDB and verified the layers should be getting removed, but for some reason they are not getting removed in the UI.

Comment: For some reason skeletonGradient is being removed correctly, but skeletonLayer is not getting removed as a sublayer. Maybe this is related to @matt's comment about skeletonLayer being both a mask and a sublayer.

Comment: So adding a separate mask layer and having that separated from the background layer (aka skeletonLayer) worked. Now removing the layers is working correctly.